# c# reread from socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to read from socket for the first time, then abort the thread which handles it and then reread again.
The weird part here is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

client:

```
private void startSend() 
{
    Image f;
    ms = new MemoryStream();
    while (true) 
    {
        f = GetDesktopImage();
        f.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        bmpBytes = (ms.ToArray());
        SendVarData(client.Client, bmpBytes);
        count++;
        ms.SetLength(0);
    }
}

private int SendVarData(Socket s, byte[] data) 
{
    total = 0;
    int size = data.Length;
    int dataleft = size;
    int sent;

    datasize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
    sent = s.Send(datasize);

    while (total < size) 
    {
        sent = s.Send(data, total, dataleft, SocketFlags.None);
        total += sent;
        dataleft -= sent;
    }
    return total;
}
```

i call the start send in a thread which always keep running in the background.

server code:

```
MemoryStream ms;
byte[] data;
public void startListening() 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        try 
        {
            data = ReceiveVarData(client.Client);
            ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            theImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            count++;
        } catch {}
    }
}

private static byte[] ReceiveVarData(Socket s) 
{
    int total = 0;
    int recv;
    byte[] datasize = new byte[4];

    recv = s.Receive(datasize, 0, 4, 0);
    int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize, 0);
    int dataleft = size;
    byte[] data = new byte[size];

    while (total < size) 
    {
        recv = s.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
        if (recv == 0) break;
        total += recv;
        dataleft -= recv;
    }
    return data;
}
```

It works great as i said first time, but than when i try to close the thread on the second form close

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    th.Abort();
}
```

and try to read again I'm just getting an error at this line

> byte[] data = new byte[size];

Error:

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

tried to print `size` value and it was something like `-2522561418`...

*of course i restart the thread again on the form opening*

```
th= new Thread(new ThreadStart(startListening));
th.Start();
```

Comment: 1. Aborting a thread and expecting your code handling external resources that have been manipulated by said thread to behave in a predictable way afterwards is... a questionable idea at best. 2. Why don't you just use a `NetworkStream` to simplify your code?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski why?isn't it simple aleardy?

Comment: Well... you could replace `SendVarData` with 2 lines of code. Same for `ReceiveVarData`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski i tried to work with networstream once...  you could see i asked a question few time ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383334/using-networkstream-with-sockets?noredirect=1#comment48856928_30383334  i just got very confused with all of the serializtion etc... by the way i tried to check the effieceint of every method and it works way faster

Comment: It works way faster because you were using `BinaryFormatter` in that other question, which is terribly slow. You could just have written `binWriter.Write(memStream.Length); memStream.Position = 0; memStream.CopyTo(netStream);` and be done with it (`binWriter` being a `BinaryWriter` over the `NetworkStream`).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski how do i receive it in the server side? im just no sure :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79251/discussion-between-itapi-and-lucas-trzesniewski).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't "reread" data from a socket that was read already. Why would you think this is possible? I don't understand the line of thought behind it.

[Thread.Abort is evil](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=#complete=1&hl=&q=thread.abort%20evil) and can't be used. As long as your code contains a call to that method your code is invalid and must be changed.

`Abort` can't abort IO anyway. The abort can happen before or after the network read. I guess that explains why sometimes "rereading" works - because the data was not read before.

Probably you should have a thread running for the duration of the connection. That thread should read everything that comes in and place it into a data structure for later retrieval. For example, a `Queue<Image>`.

In fact I'd strongly advise you to delete all this socket code and use WCF or HTTP. These protocols handle a lot of details for you.

Comment: Big +1 for "I'd strongly advise you to delete all this socket code and use WCF or HTTP"

Comment: @usr it's not actually reread...i didnt close the socket or somthing.... im just trying to stop the method of reading and than to start it again... i think i have to reset the memorystream or somthing... it's really weird cuz somtimes it does works!! i would really like someone to help me in private if he can...

Comment: I commented on all of that in my answer. I said why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I said that you can't stop and continue reading. If you did not understand what I explained then ask specifically about it.

Comment: @usr and if i'll send a command to the second side to stop sending for few secs?

Comment: That seems like a good idea as well but your code must deal with the fact that this command might take a long time and that you will still receive some images. You probably must drop those images. You are building some kind of image streaming, right? I'd build that in a "pull" manner. Have the server issue commands to the client that say "give me one image now". You can then simply end this loop if you want to stop receiving images.